# Orbeon forms - repeated sub-section

Tags: orbeon

I have repeated section (Minimum Number of Repetitions = 0; Maximum Number of Repetitions = 9). In this section it is nasted repeated sub-section (Minimum Number of Repetitions = 1; Maximum Number of Repetitions = 9). If I remove any repetition from section, then run Test and add first repetition to section, sub-section appears with no repetitions (although I have set Minimum Number of Repetitions to 1). Validator doesn't detect any error.

Is it possible to add repetition to sub-section, when I add repetition to section?

Probably I have to call sub-section template, when I add repetition to section:
<xf:insert context="path_TODO" origin="instance('sub-section-template')"/>

but I don't know how and where I should call this. Maybe somewhere here:
[image]

Example form: https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/81751a85c9206ee58ade5b1c16afeea6dc790327

Comment: There is a solution, but it currently exposed a bug into Orbeon Forms. I am looking into it and will follow-up here when we know more about this. -Alex

Comment: Just curious: did you get a chance to try the solution mentioned below? If so, did it work for you? -Alex

Comment: hey Alex, I didn't try this yet. I will try test it this week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Form Builder:

1. Add a first outer section, make it repeated; I'll call this the outer repeat.
2. Inside the section, add the repeated grid; I'll call this the inner repeat.
3. In the Section/Grid Settings for the repeated grid, check the box for *Initial number of iterations uses template*:

   [image]
4. Make sure you have 1 outer iteration, and 1 inner iteration:

   [image]
5. Edit the source of the form and add the following, just inside the `<xf:model>`:

   ```
    <fr:listener version="2018.2" modes="new" events="form-load-after-data"
                 actions="clear-outer-section"/>
    <fr:action name="clear-outer-section" version="2018.2">
        <fr:repeat-clear repeat="section-1"/>
    </fr:action>
   ```

With step 1 to 4, when users create a new iteration of the outer repeat, the number of iterations in the inner repeat will be based on what you have in Form Builder in the first iteration of the outer repeat, instead of starting with 0 iteration. Your issue is that you want to have 0 outer iterations. But if you remove the last outer iteration, we don't have an example in the data for how many inner iterations to create. Hence we keep 1 in Form Builder, and remove it as soon as the form is loaded, which is what we do in step 5 with the [action syntax](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/advanced/services-and-actions/actions-syntax).

Comment: As "section-1" I should set outer section name, right? I have modified the example form (https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/81751a85c9206ee58ade5b1c16afeea6dc790327) according to your advices, but it doesn't work as I expect. 
When I run form, the outer section should have 0 iterations, but when I add first repetition, the inner section should be added too (1 repetition).

Comment: @m.makos Yes, `section-1` is the outer section name. Your link to the form on `demo.orbeon.com` isn't working right now; have you deleted the form there? If not, maybe somebody else did. Alternatively, you could also upload the source to a Gist (https://gist.github.com/).

Comment: @Alex, here is new example form: https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/1365f3e13ea14fd5b1925214caac6587d3943ef4 . Here is source code: https://gist.github.com/mmakos-profidata/efc4a942e9a7c2cae724cef31a4ed6b1

Comment: @m.makos got it, thank you for the example; your example works, but I imagine that you didn't see the first iteration being removed because you were using Test, and the code you added using the action syntax on the run when you open the `/new` page, so this isn't some thing that you can test with Test in Form Builder. https://i.imgur.com/xF2MY4R.gif Also, a little thing: you can put your code using the action syntax at the beginning of the model, so you can see it right away after you click on edit source.

Comment: @m.makos Excellent, I am glad we cleared that up.